# Visual Studio 2013 C++/CLI Intellisense with Reference Library

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, cuda, c++-cli, intellisense

I have a solution with multiple projects within it.

- Project1 is a C++/CLI mixed mode project.
- Project2 is a C++/CLI mixed mode project with CUDA support (the CUDA compiler is used for *.cu and *.cuh files).

Project2 includes Project1 via the `Common Properties->References` interface in Project2's properties. **Everything compiles perfectly fine**; however, intellisense highlights any reference in project2's code to project1 as an error. Specifically I get the following types of messages.

In my *.h file in project2

```
#pragma once
namespace Project2
{
    class TypeInProject2
    {
        property Project1::TypeInProject1^ obj 
        { 
            Project1::TypeInProject1^ get();
            void set(Project1::TypeInProject1^ value);
        };
        //"Project1" is underlined in red
        //IntelliSense: name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace
    };
}
```

I can make intellisense happy by adding an include to the header in project1 but this results in redefinitions of all of the project1's classes and raises compile errors.

Are there any quirks I should know about in the C++/CLI project options to make intellisense happy?

---

Update: I should add that sometimes everything works correctly. But after exiting VS13 and then reopening the project all of the intellisense errors show up again.

Comment: There is no obvious reason for this.  An indirect one, the IntelliSense parser does need the metadata from the compiled Project1 assembly to do its job.  If that assembly doesn't exist yet, or is outdated, then it does inevitably get stumped.  A quick recompile ought to cure such an issue.

Comment: Recompiling / reloading either project doesn't resolve it. I explicitly stated that project2 is a C++/CLI project with CUDA. I've never had this issue without including the CUDA compiler.

Comment: Someone edited my question and removed the CUDA tag, but I think the CUDA support is the linchpin here--overzealous admin.

Comment: I removed the CUDA tag, because this doesn't, on the face of it, seem to have *anything* to do with CUDA programming or CUDA. This seems to be a question about intellisense and Visual Studio (and I am not an over zealous admin, I am the guy who answers a good proportion of the questions on the CUDA tag). Help me out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that the Intellisense database is screwed up. Here's what I've done to correct it when it happens to me:

1. Make sure your code is in a state where everything will compile.
2. Exit Visual Studio
3. Delete the .suo and .sdf files in the solution's directory. (Deleting the .suo probably isn't necessary to this cleanup process, but it doesn't hurt.)
4. Open the solution in Visual Studio.
5. Select Build --> Batch Build.
6. In the Batch Build window, click "Select All", and then "Rebuild".

Comment: I followed these steps exactly. It did not affect the intellisense problem. I made sure that all build configurations build and run correctly.

Comment: I take that back. Repeating step 2 and 4 several times seems to have inexplicably helped. It looks like intellisense is working now. Great! I've been dealing with all these senseless errors for weeks.